# Find the exact value of $\int_{0}^{2}x[\frac{1}{x}]dx$.

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals

Find the exact value of $\int_{0}^{2}x\left[\frac{1}{x}\right]dx$.

Let $[x]$ denote $\lceil{x-\frac{1}{2}}\rceil$.

Using [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/3hlvyraytq), I got $2.46736022133$ and [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Integrate%5Bx+round%5C%2840%29Divide%5B1%2Cx%5D%5C%2841%29%2C%7Bx%2C0%2C1%7D%5D) does not give me a solution. My intuition tells me that it might be possible to find an exact value using Trapezoidal Reimann Sums but I am not really sure how to go about doing it. After my attempt, I got stuck but I was at a point where I could plug it into [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%5Csum_%7Bn%3D1%7D%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7D%5Cfrac%7B16n%5E%7B2%7D%7D%7B%5Cleft%284n%5E%7B2%7D-1%5Cright%29%5E%7B2%7D%7D) and it gave me $\frac{\pi^2}{4}$. Why did it come out so nicely?

My attempt:

Where $A_n$ denotes the area of the $nth$ trapezoid from the right:
$$A=\frac{h}{2}(a+b)$$
$$A_n=\frac{\frac{2}{2n-1}-\frac{2}{2n+1}}{2}(\frac{2n}{2n-1}+\frac{2n}{2n+1})$$
$$A_n=\frac{\frac{4n+2}{4n^{2}-1}-\frac{4n-2}{4n^{2}-1}}{2}\left(\frac{4n^{2}+2n}{4n^{2}-1}+\frac{4n^{2}-2n}{4n^{2}-1}\right)$$
$$A_n=\frac{2}{4n^{2}-1}\left(\frac{8n^{2}}{4n^{2}-1}\right)$$
$$A_n=\frac{16n^{2}}{\left(4n^{2}-1\right)^{2}}$$

Then:
$$\int_{0}^{2}x\left[\frac{1}{x}\right]dx=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{16n^{2}}{\left(4n^{2}-1\right)^{2}}$$
I do not know how to solve this infinite summation so I plugged it into WolframAlpha and it gave me $\frac{\pi^2}{4}$. How did it get to this conclusion? Is there a more efficient way to solve this?

Comment: What is the definition $[\cdot ]$? You say "standard rounding function" but there exists for example floor $\lfloor \cdot \rfloor$ and $\lceil\cdot \rceil$ functions that and both round (one down and one up).

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/636137/42969 or https://math.stackexchange.com/q/810398/42969

Comment: @A.P. based on the Desmos link it seems to be "round to nearest".

Comment: WA's definition of `round` seems to be$$\left[\frac1x\right]:=\left\lceil\frac1x-\frac12\right\rceil=\left\lfloor\frac1x+\frac12\right\rfloor$$

Comment: There is no standard definition for the rounding function. Particularly because there's no natural choice to round the number of the form $n + \frac{1}{2}$. You'll find different definitions in various sources.

Comment: Assuming your calculation is right so far, telescope with$$\frac{16n^2}{(4n^2-1)^2}-\frac{2}{(2n+1)^2}=a_n-a_{n+1},\,a_n:=\frac{2n}{(2n-1)^2},$$then use $\sum_{n=1}\frac{1}{(2n+1)^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{8}-1$.

Comment: [Wolfram Alpha knows](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=approximate+integral+x+round%281%2Fx%29%2C+x%3D+0+..+2) how to approximate the integral

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Continuing where you left off. Note
\begin{align*}
&\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{16n^2}{4n^2-1} \\
&= 2\sum_{n=1}^\infty n\left(\frac{1}{(2n-1)^2} - \frac{1}{(2n+1)^2}\right)\\
&= 2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\sum_{k=1}^n 1\right) \left(\frac{1}{(2n-1)^2} - \frac{1}{(2n+1)^2}\right)\\
&= 2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^n \left(\frac{1}{(2n-1)^2} - \frac{1}{(2n+1)^2}\right)\\
&= 2\sum_{k=1}^\infty \sum_{n=k}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{(2n-1)^2} - \frac{1}{(2n+1)^2}\right)\\
&= 2\sum_{k=1}^\infty \sum_{n=k}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{(2n-1)^2}\right) - \sum_{n=k+1}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{(2n-1)^2}\right)\\
&= 2\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2k-1)^2} \\
&= 2\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2} - \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2k)^2}\right) \\
&= 2\cdot\frac{3}{4}\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{k^2} \\
&= 2\cdot\frac{3}{4}\cdot\frac{\pi^2}{6} = \frac{\pi^2}{4}
\end{align*}

Comment: Between lines 4-5, I use a similar trick to switching the order of integration for iterated integrals. Between 5-7, it's the telescoping series stuff. For line 7, I note that it's the sum of reciporals of squares of odd naturals, so it's the sum of recip square all naturals minus recip square even naturals

Answer (score 6):

- If $[x]:=n$ iff $n-\tfrac12< x\leq n+\tfrac12$ (i.e. $[x]=\lceil x-\tfrac12\rceil$, which seems to be what the OP had in mind), then
  \begin{align}
  \int^2_0  x[1/x]\,dx & =\sum^\infty_{n=1}\int_{[\tfrac{2}{2n+1},\tfrac2{2n-1})}nx\,dx\\
  &=\sum^\infty_{n=1}\Big(\frac{2n-1+1}{(2n-1)^2}-\frac{2n+1-1}{(2n+1)^2}\Big)\\
  &=\sum^\infty_{n=1}\Big(\frac{1}{2n-1}-\frac{1}{2n+1}+\frac{1}{(2n-1)^2}+\frac{1}{(2n+1)^2}\Big)\\
  &=1+2\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{1}{(2n-1)^2}-1=2\Big(\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{1}{n^2}-\frac14\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac1{n^2}\Big)\\
  &=\frac{\pi^2}{4}
  \end{align}
- The same estimate holds when $[x]:=n$ iff $n-\tfrac12 \leq x<n+\tfrac12$ (i.e., $[x]=\lfloor x+\tfrac12\rfloor$) since $\lceil x-\tfrac12\rceil=\lfloor x+\tfrac12\rfloor$ a.s.

---

- If by $[\cdot]$ the OP means the ceiling function $\lceil x\rceil=n$ where $n-1<x\leq n$, then
  $$\int^2_0 x\lceil 1/x \rceil\,dx=\int^1_0  x\lceil 1/x \rceil\,dx +\int^2_1 x\,dx=\int^1_0 x\lceil 1/x\rceil \,dx + \frac32$$
  From
  \begin{align}
  \int^1_0  x\lceil 1/x \rceil\,dx & =\sum^\infty_{n=2}\int_{[\tfrac{1}{n},\tfrac1{n-1})}nx\,dx=\sum^\infty_{n=2}\frac{n}{2}\Big(\frac{1}{(n-1)^2}-\frac{1}{n^2}\Big)\\
  &=\sum^\infty_{n=2}\frac{2n-1}{2n(n-1)^2}=\sum^\infty_{n=2}\frac{1}{(n-1)^2}+\frac{n-1-n}{2n(n-1)^2}\\
  &=\frac12\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{1}{n^2}+\frac12\sum^\infty_{n=2}\frac{1}{n(n-1)} =\frac{\pi^2}{12}+\frac12
  \end{align}
  The value of the integral in this case is  $\frac{\pi^2}{12}+2\approx 2.822467$
- If the OP means $[\cdot]$ to be the integer part function (floor function) $\lfloor x\rfloor =n$ iff $n\leq x<n+1$, then
  $$\int^2_0 x\lfloor 1/x \lfloor\,dx=\int^1_0  x\lfloor 1/x \rfloor\,dx +\int^2_1 0\cdot x\,dx=\int^1_0 x\lfloor 1/x\rfloor \,dx $$
  The value of the integral is then given by
  \begin{align}
  \int^1_0  x\lfloor 1/x \rfloor\,dx & =\sum^\infty_{n=1}\int_{(\tfrac{1}{n+1},\tfrac1n]}nx\,dx=\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{n}{2}\Big(\frac{1}{n^2}-\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\Big)\\
  &=\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{2n+1}{2n(n+1)^2}=\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}+\frac{n+1-n}{2n(n+1)^2}\\
  &=\frac12\sum^\infty_{n=2}\frac{1}{n^2}-\frac12\sum^\infty_{n=1}\frac{1}{n(n+1)} =\frac{\pi^2}{12}
  \end{align}

Answer (score 4):

An alternate solution:

$$
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{2}x\operatorname{round}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)dx &= \int_0^2 x\Biggl\lfloor{\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{2}\Biggr\rfloor}dx \tag{1}\\
&= 8\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{\lfloor{x\rfloor}}{\left(2x-1\right)^{3}}dx \tag{2}\\
&= 8\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n\int_{n}^{n+1}\frac{dx}{\left(2x-1\right)^{3}} \\
&= 16\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^{2}}{\left(1-4n^{2}\right)^{2}} \\
\end{align}
$$

where in $(1)$ we used the Desmos interpretation $\displaystyle \operatorname{round}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) := \Biggl\lfloor{\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{2}\Biggr\rfloor}$ and in $(2)$ we used the mapping $\displaystyle \frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{2} \mapsto x$.

Next, let $f$ be a piecewise smooth function on $[0,L]$. Then the Fourier sine expansion is given by

$$f\left(x\right)\ =\ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_{n}\sin\left(\frac{\pi nx}{L}\right)$$

where we have the sequence

$$b_{n}=\frac{2}{L}\int_{0}^{L}f\left(x\right)\sin\left(\frac{\pi nx}{L}\right)dx.$$

Let $f(x) = \cos(x)$ and $L = \dfrac{\pi}{2}$. Then using some basic integration, we can prove that

$$b_{n}=\frac{4}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos\left(x\right)\sin\left(2nx\right)dx\ =\ \frac{4}{\pi}\cdot\frac{2n}{4n^{2}-1}.$$

This means

$$
\begin{align}
\cos\left(x\right) &= \frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2n}{4n^{2}-1}\sin\left(2nx\right) \\
\implies \cos^2(x) &=  \frac{8}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n\cos\left(x\right)\sin\left(2nx\right)}{4n^{2}-1} \\
\implies \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos^{2}\left(x\right)dx &= \frac{8}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{4n^{2}-1}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos\left(x\right)\sin\left(2nx\right)dx \\
&= \frac{8}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n}{4n^{2}-1}\cdot\frac{2n}{4n^{2}-1}. \\
&= \frac{16}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^{2}}{\left(4n^{2}-1\right)^{2}} \\
\end{align}
$$

But $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\cos^{2}\left(x\right)dx=\frac{\pi}{4}$. By transitivity, we get

$$\frac{\pi}{4}=\frac{16}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^{2}}{\left(4n^{2}-1\right)^{2}}.$$

Therefore,

$$\int_{0}^{2}x\operatorname{round}\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)dx = \frac{\pi^{2}}{4}.$$

Answer (score 4):

$$\frac{16 n^2}{\left(4 n^2-1\right)^2}=-\frac{1}{2 n+1}+\frac{1}{(2 n+1)^2}+\frac{1}{2 n-1}+\frac{1}{(2 n-1)^2}$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^p\frac{16 n^2}{\left(4 n^2-1\right)^2}=\frac{1}{2} \left(\psi ^{(0)}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)-\psi
   ^{(0)}\left(p+\frac{3}{2}\right)\right)+$$
$$\frac{1}{8} \left(-2 \psi ^{(1)}\left(p+\frac{3}{2}\right)+\pi
   ^2-8\right)+$$ $$\frac{1}{2} \left(\psi ^{(0)}\left(p+\frac{1}{2}\right)-\psi
   ^{(0)}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)+
\frac{1}{8} \left(\pi ^2-2 \psi
   ^{(1)}\left(p+\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)$$

Using the asymptotics
$$\sum_{n=1}^p\frac{16 n^2}{\left(4 n^2-1\right)^2}=\frac{\pi ^2}{4}-\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{2
   p^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^3}\right)$$

Answer (score 3):

Another way to get the sum of the series
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{16n^2}{(4n^2-1)^2}
$$
without double summations and without switching the order of the sums.
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{16n^2}{(4n^2-1)^2} 
&= \sum_{n=1}^N \left[ \frac{2n}{(2n-1)^2} - \frac{2n}{(2n+1)^2} \right] \\[2pt]
&= 2 \sum_{n=1}^N \frac1{(2n-1)^2} 
+ \sum_{n=1}^N \left[ \frac{2(n-1)}{(2n-1)^2} - \frac{2n}{(2n+1)^2} \right] \\[2pt]
&= 2 \left( \sum_{n=1}^{2N-1} \frac1{n^2} 
- \sum_{n=1}^{N-1} \frac1{(2n)^2} \right) 
+ \left[ 0 - \frac2{3^2} + \frac2{3^2} -\frac4{5^2} + \dots{} \right. \\[2pt] 
&\quad+ \left. \frac{2(N-1)}{(2N-1)^2} - \frac{2N}{(2N+1)^2} \right] \\[2pt]
&= 2 \left( \sum_{n=1}^{2N-1} \frac1{n^2} 
- \frac14 \sum_{n=1}^{N-1} \frac1{n^2} \right) 
- \frac{2N}{(2N+1)^2}\,.
\end{align}

Hence,
\begin{align} 
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{16n^2}{(4n^2-1)^2}
&= \lim_{N\to\infty} \left[ \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{16n^2}{(4n^2-1)^2} \right] \\[2pt]
&= \lim_{N\to\infty}\left[2\left(\sum_{n=1}^{2N-1}\frac1{n^2}-\frac14\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}\frac1{n^2}\right)-\frac{2N}{\left(2N+1\right)^2}\right] \\[2pt]
&= 2 \left( \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac1{n^2} -\frac14 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac1{n^2} \right) \\[2pt]
&= 2 \left( \frac{\pi^2}6 - \frac14\!\cdot\!\frac{\pi^2}6 \right) \\[2pt] 
&= 2 \left(1 - \frac14\right) \frac{\pi^2}6 \\[2pt]
&= 2 \!\cdot\! \frac34\!\cdot\! \frac{\pi^2}6 \\[2pt] 
&= \frac{\pi^2}4\,.
\end{align}

Comment: Instead of `$\displaystyle <math>$` you can use the default *displaystyle* formatting (and it comes out centered) with `$$ <math> $$` which is just shorthand for wrapping your math in the *equation* environment: `\begin{equation} <math> \end{equation}`. Also, for line up equal signs, the *align* environment is very nice. More formatting info [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Great solution, btw! It's good to remember that infinite series are limits of finite sums *by definition* and those finite sums are sometimes easier to deal with.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a crazy and over-the-top method using contour integration.

$$
\bbox[15px,#FFFAFD,border:6px groove #0712FF  ]{\int_0^2 x \Biggl\lceil{\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{2}\Biggl\rceil}dx = \frac{\pi^2}{4}}
$$

---

***PROOF.*** Let the integral equal $\mathcal{I}$. Using the transformation $\displaystyle \frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{2} \mapsto x$, we get

$$
\begin{align}
\mathcal{I} &= \int_0^2 x \Biggl\lceil{\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{2}\Biggl\rceil}dx \\
&= \int_0^2 x \Biggl\lfloor{\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{2}\Biggl\rfloor}dx \\
&\overset{\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{2} \mapsto x}= 8\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{\lfloor{x\rfloor}}{\left(2x-1\right)^{3}}dx \\
&= 8\sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}^+} k\int_{k}^{k+1}\frac{dx}{\left(2x-1\right)^{3}} \\
&= 16\sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}^+}\frac{k^{2}}{\left(4k^{2}-1\right)^{2}} \\
&= 8\sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}}\frac{k^{2}}{\left(4k^{2}-1\right)^{2}}\,. \\
\end{align}
$$

In that last equality, note that the sequence of terms $\displaystyle \frac{k^2}{(4k^2-1)^2}$ for negative $k$ equals that of positive $k$.

---

We define a function $\displaystyle f: \mathbb{C} \,\backslash \left(\mathbb{Z}^+ \cup \mathbb{Z}^- \cup \left\{-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right\}\right) \to \mathbb{C}$ such that $\displaystyle z \mapsto \frac{z^2 \cot(\pi z)}{(4z^2-1)^2}$. We also construct a counterclockwise circular contour and a set of poles

$$
\begin{align}
C_n &:= \left\{t \in [0,2\pi]\,:\,\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)e^{it}\right\} \\
\mathcal{P}_n &:= \overbrace{\left(\left\{-n,-n+1,\ldots,n-1,n\right\}\,\backslash \left\{0\right\}\right) \cup \left\{-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right\}}^\text{set of simple poles}
\end{align}
$$

where $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$. The visual above depicts the contour $C_n$ enclosing $\mathcal{P}_n$ over the rainbow phase plot of $f$ with shading.

[image]

Notice that $z=0$ is a removable singularity. Writing $\displaystyle \frac{z}{e^{\pi iz}-1}$ as an asymptotic Taylor expansion centered at $z=0$, we get

$$
\begin{align}
f(z) &= \frac{z^2\cot(\pi z)}{(4z^2-1)^2} \\
&= \frac{iz\left(1+e^{2\pi iz}\right)}{\left(4z^{2}-1\right)^{2}\left(e^{\pi iz}+1\right)}\cdot\frac{z}{e^{\pi iz}-1} \\
&= \frac{iz\left(1+e^{2\pi iz}\right)}{\left(4z^{2}-1\right)^{2}\left(e^{\pi iz}+1\right)}\cdot\left(-\frac{i}{\pi}-\frac{1}{2}z+\frac{i\pi}{12}z^{2}+\mathcal{O}\left(z^{4}\right)\right)\,.
\end{align}
$$

This expansion makes it possible to redefine $f$ such that it's analytic in a neighborhood of $0$ and remove $z=0$ as a singularity.

Employing [Cauchy's Residue Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem), we get

$$
\oint_{C_n}f(z)dz = 2\pi i\sum_{k \,\in\, P_n}\mathop{\mathrm{Res}}_{z\,=\,k}f(z) = 2\pi i \left(\sum_{k\,=\,-n}^{n}\mathop{\mathrm{Res}}_{z\,=\,k} f(z) +\mathop{\mathrm{Res}}_{z\,=\,-\frac{1}{2}}f(z) + \mathop{\mathrm{Res}}_{z\,=\,\frac{1}{2}}f(z)\right)
$$

---

Evaluating the residue at $\displaystyle z=-\frac{1}{2}$ of $f(z)dz$, we get

$$
\begin{align}
2\pi i\mathop{\mathrm{Res}}_{z\,=\,-\frac{1}{2}}f(z) &= 2\pi i \lim_{z\,\to\,-\frac{1}{2}}\left(z+\frac{1}{2}\right)\cdot\frac{iz^{2}\left(1+e^{2\pi iz}\right)}{16\left(z-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2}\left(z+\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2}\left(e^{2\pi iz}-1\right)} \\
&= -\frac{\pi}{8}\lim_{z\,\to\,-\frac{1}{2}}\frac{z^{2}}{\left(z-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2}\left(e^{2\pi iz}-1\right)} \lim_{z\,\to\,-\frac{1}{2}}\frac{1+e^{2\pi iz}}{z+\frac{1}{2}} \\
&= -\frac{\pi}{8}\cdot\frac{\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2}}{\left(-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2}\left(e^{2\pi i\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)}-1\right)}\cdot \lim_{z\,\to\,-\frac{1}{2}}\frac{\frac{d}{dz}\left(1+e^{2\pi iz}\right)}{\frac{d}{dz}\left(z+\frac{1}{2}\right)} \\
&= \frac{\pi}{64}\lim_{z\,\to\,-\frac{1}{2}}\frac{2\pi ie^{2\pi iz}}{1} \\
&= \frac{\pi}{64}\cdot2\pi ie^{2\pi i\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)} \\
&= -\frac{i\pi^{2}}{32}\,. \\
\end{align}
$$

The same process should apply for calculating the residue at $\displaystyle z=\frac{1}{2}$. It should be

$$
2\pi i\mathop{\mathrm{Res}}_{z\,=\,\frac{1}{2}}f(z) = -\frac{i\pi^2}{32}\,.
$$

Calculating the rest of the residues, we get

$$
\begin{align}
2\pi i \sum_{k\,=\,-n}^{n}\mathop{\mathrm{Res}}_{z\,=\,k} f(z) &= 2\pi i \lim_{z\,\to\,k} \frac{iz^{2}\left(1+e^{2\pi iz}\right)}{\frac{d}{dz}\left(4z^{2}-1\right)^{2}\left(e^{2\pi iz}-1\right)}\\
&= -2\pi\sum_{k\,=\,-n}^{n}\lim_{z\,\to\,k}\frac{z^{2}\left(1+e^{2\pi iz}\right)}{2\left(4z^{2}-1\right)\left(4\pi iz^{2}e^{2\pi iz}+8ze^{2\pi iz}-8z-i\pi e^{2\pi iz}\right)}\\
&=-2\pi\sum_{k=-n}^{n}\frac{k^{2}\left(1+e^{2\pi ik}\right)}{2\left(4k^{2}-1\right)\left(4\pi ik^{2}e^{2\pi ik}+8ke^{2\pi ik}-8k-i\pi e^{2\pi ik}\right)} \tag{1}\\
&= 2i\sum_{k=-n}^{n}\frac{k^{2}}{\left(4k^{2}-1\right)^{2}}\,. \\
\end{align}
$$

In $(1)$, we use the piecewise equality

$$
e^{k\pi i} = 
\begin{cases}
  1 & k \equiv 0 \pmod{2} \\
  -1 & k \equiv 1 \pmod{2}\,. \\
\end{cases}
$$

Equating the imaginary part on both sides of the equality that resulted from Cauchy's Residue Theorem and applying $n \to \infty$, we recover the infinite series we want as follows:

$$
\lim_{n\,\to\,\infty}\Im\oint_{C_n}\frac{z^{2}\cot\left(\pi z\right)}{\left(4z^{2}-1\right)^{2}} = \sum_{k\,\in\,\mathbb{Z}}\frac{2k^{2}}{\left(4k^{2}-1\right)^{2}} - \frac{\pi^{2}}{16}
$$

$$
\implies \sum_{k\,\in\,\mathbb{Z}}\frac{k^{2}}{\left(4k^{2}-1\right)^{2}} = \frac{1}{2}\lim_{n\,\to\,\infty}\Im\oint_{C_n}\frac{z^{2}\cot\left(\pi z\right)}{\left(4z^{2}-1\right)^{2}}+\frac{\pi^2}{32}\,.
$$

All that's left is to evaluate the limit of that contour integral and multiply both sides by $8$ to get the desired answer.

---

We construct a sequence of contour integrals $\displaystyle \oint_{C_n}f$ such that $\displaystyle  \oint_{C_n}f$ converges as $n \to \infty$. As the contour grows bigger, none of the integer poles touch it because we judiciously constructed $C_n$ such that $\displaystyle \Re\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)e^{it}$ always lies in between two poles. A visual I made on Desmos can be found [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/xcpuiaxirv) and playing with the $n$ slider.

Letting $z \in C_n$, we use the parameterization $\displaystyle z = \left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)e^{it}$ on $[0,2\pi]$. We bound the contour integral's modulus and have the following chain of inequalities below:

$$
\begin{align}
0 &\leq \left|\Im \oint_{C_n}f(z)dz\right| \\
&\leq \left|\oint_{C_n}f(z)dz\right| \\
&= \underbrace{\left|\operatorname{\Large\int_{0}^{2\pi}}\frac{\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2}e^{2it}\cot\left(\pi\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)e^{it}\right)}{\left(4\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2}e^{2it}-1\right)^{2}}\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)ie^{it}dt\right|}_{z \, \in\, C_n} \\
&\leq \operatorname{\Large\int_{0}^{2\pi}}\left|\frac{\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2}e^{2it}\cot\left(\pi\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)e^{it}\right)}{\left(4\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2}e^{2it}-1\right)^{2}}\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)ie^{it}\right|dt \\
&= \operatorname{\Large\int_{0}^{2\pi}}\frac{\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)^{3}\left|\cot\left(\pi\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)e^{it}\right)\right|}{\left|4\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2}e^{2it}-1\right|^{2}}dt \\
&\leq \frac{\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)^{3}}{\left(4\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2}-1\right)^{2}}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\left|\cot\left(\pi\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)e^{it}\right)\right|dt \\
&= \frac{\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)^{3}}{\left(4\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2}-1\right)^{2}}\operatorname{\large\int_{0}^{2\pi}}\left|i+\frac{2i}{\exp\left(2\pi\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)ie^{it}\right)-1}\right|dt \\
&\leq \frac{\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)^{3}}{\left(4\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2}-1\right)^{2}}\operatorname{\large\int_{0}^{2\pi}}\left(1+\frac{2}{\left|\exp\left(2\pi\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)ie^{it}\right)-1\right|}\right)dt \\
&\leq \frac{\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)^{3}}{\left(4\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2}-1\right)^{2}}\operatorname{\large\int_{0}^{2\pi}}\mathop{\mathrm{sup}}_{t \in [0,2\pi]}\left(1+\frac{2}{\left|\exp\left(2\pi\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)ie^{it}\right)-1\right|}\right)dt \\
&= \frac{2\pi\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)^{3}}{\left(4\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2}-1\right)^{2}}\mathop{\mathrm{sup}}_{t \in [0,2\pi]}\left(1+\frac{2}{\left|\exp\left(2\pi\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)ie^{it}\right)-1\right|}\right)\,.
\end{align}
$$

Here, we bound the integral by its supremum because the graph of $\displaystyle 1+\frac{2}{\left|\exp\left(2\pi\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)ie^{it}\right)-1\right|}$ is a [square-looking wave](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/rz3epwgiuo) for large $n$ periodic on $2\pi$.

Applying $n \to \infty$, we get

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} 0 \leq \lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\Im \oint_{C_n}f(z)dz\right| \leq \frac{2\pi\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)^{3}}{\left(4\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2}-1\right)^{2}}\mathop{\mathrm{sup}}_{t \in [0,2\pi]}\left(1+\frac{2}{\left|\exp\left(2\pi\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)ie^{it}\right)-1\right|}\right)\,.
$$

Since the supremum is fixed and the numerator grows slower than the denominator, we can use the [Squeeze Theorem for sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem#Statement) to get

$$
\begin{align}
&\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\Im \oint_{C_n}f(z)dz\right| = 0 \\
\implies 
&\bbox[15px,#DBFFEA]{\lim_{n\to\infty}\Im \oint_{C_n}f(z)dz = 0\,.} \\
\end{align}
$$

---

Wrapping things up,

$$
\require{cancel}{\sum_{k\,\in\,\mathbb{Z}}\frac{k^{2}}{\left(4k^{2}-1\right)^{2}} = \frac{1}{2}\cancelto{0}{\lim_{n\,\to\,\infty}\Im\oint_{C_n}\frac{z^{2}\cot\left(\pi z\right)}{\left(4z^{2}-1\right)^{2}}}+\frac{\pi^2}{32}\,.}
$$

Then we just multiply both sides by $8$. Finally, we conclude that

$$
\bbox[15px,#E7FCFF,border:6px groove #51008C ]{\int_0^2 x \Biggl\lceil{\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{2}\Biggl\rceil}dx = \frac{\pi^2}{4}}
$$

and we're finally done! $\blacksquare$

***Happy New Year :)***